# How to restore the Alt-code to é and similar mappings on Word 2003 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, special-characters

I used to be able to type Alt+0233 to get an e-acute (é) on Word 2003 on Windows 10, and I could also use various other Alt-code combinations, all beginning 02, to get other characters with diacritics, plus Alt+164 when I needed an ñ. But now several of the combinations no longer work. For example, instead of é I get some kind of tab or long space when I type Alt+0233. A few combinations still work, giving for example àâôùñ. Ones that don't work include çèéêíïû.

How can I restore the previous position?

Comment: Some fonts don't support those characters. Are you using a different font?

Comment: I am using the same font, Times New Roman, but the problem exists with other fonts too that I use more rarely. Something has changed. I just don't know what.

Comment: On my keyboard, using ALT and digits only works if Numlock is on for my numeric keypad.